# Python 3 - attachment error

Tags: python

I am trying to automate a daily email to one recipient using a Python3 script. That email is supposed to carry an attachment.

At the moment I am trying the below Python 3.5 code, which **incredibly** run successfully one time only.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

fromaddr = "me@home.net"
toaddr = "theother@home.biz"

msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "Daily report"

body = "Email text"

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

filename = 'DAILY REPORT.xls'
attachment = open('Z:\\DAILY REPORT.xls', "rb")
part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload(attachment).read()
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" %     filename)

msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.server.biz', 25)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "apasswordhere")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

After the first time it worked (and an email+attachment was received), it does not seem to work anymore. The exception I continuously get is:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    part.set_payload(attachment).read()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Please note that the file to be attached to the email messange and the python script are on a remote NAS, locally monted as Z: on a Windows Server 2012.
On this system I have both Pyton2 and Python3 installed, in two different directories. When python.exe is called from the consolle my system defaults on Python2, but I get the same error if I explocitly run my script using Python3.
Also running the script in my editor (Pyecharm which defaults on Python3 console) throws the same error.

Being really puzzled, I will appreciate any comment to address what I doing wrongly

Comment: What do you expect the line `part.set_payload(attachment).read()` to do?  It looks like you meant to put that first `)` at the end: `part.set_payload(attachment.read())`

Comment: Thank you for helping, your comment resolved my issue. I was unable to see my error.

Comment: @J_CsT: If you found the answer to your question, then post the answer and accept it. It benefits to everyone.

Comment: @VincentSavard I'd love you, but I really can not see where to post and and accept. I read that the relevant switch should appear in like 15 minutes, but after almost 30 mins nothing shows up. Sorry, perhaps I'm numb and newby. Thanks

Comment: @J_CsT: If you scroll down, there's a text field where you can write an answer. Write what was the answer to your question, and post it. Then you can accept the answer after 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was in this line:

```
part.set_payload(attachment).read()
```

Which was supposed to be:

```
part.set_payload(attachment.read())
```

The error was spotted by @jwodder